# UISearchBar Scope Bar Method

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` in my app.and I want the `four` Scope bars in this `UISearchBar` that I  have given from the `XIB` file .say `one , two , three and four`  and now Problem is I have four `array` s which contains separates values for each array ..say `array one` , `array two` , `array three` and `array  four` .

Now I want when I search on pressing scope bar `one` only `array one` values should search ..
on pressing scope bar `two`  only `array two`values should search and so on ..

Is there any  method for scope bar button available to search ?

like `If( scope_bar==1){...}else`

like If i search for scope bar`one` then it will display only `array one`. is there any method available ..I searched on the apple documentation but could not get

Answer (score 0):

You should read some tutorials about NSDictionary . i have implemented this search on book search app where titles and authors were searched both at same time.

// for each book

```
NSDictionary * book = NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
title, @"TITLE", author, @"AUTHOR", nil];
[dataSource addObject:book];
```

after that in search method you can make changes according to your own ease

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

[tableData removeAllObjects];

if(searchText != nil && ![searchText isEqualToString:@""]){

    for(NSDictionary * book in dataSource){
        NSString * title = [book objectForKey:@"TITLE"];
        NSString * author = [book objectForKey:@"AUTHOR"];

        NSRange titleRange = [[title lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];
        NSRange authorRange = [[author lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];

        if(titleRange.location != NSNotFound || authorRange.location != NSNotFound)
            [tableData addObject:book];
        }

}

[tableView reloadData];
}
```